# How to create a single process but multithreads MFC GUI application with MPI?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, mpi

All I need is just to write a simple MFC Windows application using MSMPI, but I don't want to launch multiple processes as my GUI application may need some user interaction before the multi-threading part. For instance, I'd like to create 2 threads after click a 'Run' button.

I have tried to run my program using the command line: mpiexec.exe -n 2 myprogram.exe but this will create two processes and I will see two application windows.

I have also tried the MPI cluster debugging option in Visual Studio 2010 but it creates two processes as well.

This seems to be a very basic question but I find it difficult to find an answer in Google.

**Edit**

To eliminate the confusion here, I have to clarify a few things:

1. I have a very complicated and large codebase that already uses MS-MPI *to achieve parallelism* and I have to build a MFC GUI on top of it. For this reason, I **cannot** use any other parallelism mechanism such as std::thread because that will mean I have to rewrite a lot of things which is not affordable.
2. **From my understanding, to launch a MPI program, I have to run the external program called mpiexec.exe in Windows. I haven't figured out if it is possible to launch the program by its own and still achieve MPI features.** I'm quite new to MPI. I'm not so sure if it is possible to achieve what I'm asking for. If it is not, I would be very appreciated if anyone can let me know why and possible workaround.

Simply put, I want to create a MFC GUI wrapper for a MPI enabled software and this has to be a multithreading program instead of  multiple instances (processes) of this GUI wrapped program (e.g. running this program by mpiexec -n 2 xxx.exe will just create 2 instances of the same program)

Comment: Why do you insist on using MPI? Have you explored std::thread?

Comment: I will not insist on using MPI if the existing code base is not implemented using MPI. Now I need to build a GUI for this code and that's why I ended up here - the description in my question is just a simplified scenario.

Comment: Well, is the existing codebase in MPI? If it's not, then I recommend using std::thread unless you have specific reason to use MPI

Comment: Yes, the existing codebase is in MPI. So I don't have a choice.

Comment: But for something so simple, I still don't see the downside in using std::thread.

Comment: I have said in my above comment the description of my question is just a simplified scenario - it's just easier for other people to understand my question. But the actual codebase is much more complicated than this and I can't rewrite everything using std::thread.

Comment: MPI is not a multi-threading library; it is a message passing library. In fact, while some recent implementations of MPI have a thread-safe option, it isn't uniformly well supported so many people avoid it - i.e. even if their program uses threads they use MPI only from one thread. MPI doesn't manage threads; it may tolerate them, depending on your implementation.

Comment: Do you, or do you not want to create a new thread? You equivocate on this - on one hand you directly say that you want to create a new thread, but then you complain about rewriting code. If you do want to create a new thread, i.e. add new code, such that the main  thread is not blocked, then why not use `std::thread` or `AfxBeginThread`

Comment: @rhashimoto, thanks for letting me know that. The existing program that I have already uses MPI to achieve parallelism. I haven't figured out whether it can be multithreading program or has to be multiprocess program. If it can't be multithreaded, as long as it has the parallelism implemented, I would like to add a GUI for the user. That's my major concern.

Comment: @Straight Line, please see my Edit above.

Comment: "I have a very complicated and large codebase that already uses MS-MPI to achieve parallelism and I have to build a MFC GUI on top of it. For this reason, I cannot use any other parallelism mechanism such as std::thread because that will mean I have to rewrite a lot of things which is not affordable." No, you are wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're creating some kind of graphical front-end for some MPI software you have. As far as I can see you have two options.

## Option 1

Create a separate Win32 application (without MPI) that is your GUI, let this application run "mpiexec" or equivalent with the correct parameters to start the application when the user requests to.

## Option 2

You need to make sure you only launch the GUI on one MPI instance. You do this by looking up the ID of the current program from MPI during startup and if it is 0, start the GUI.

Something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int myid;
    ...
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    ...
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);
    if(myid == 0){
        launchGui();
    }else{
        waitForAndProcessMessages();
    }
    ...
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously you still need to fill in all the bits an pieces to make MPI function as you normally would but in this example the first launched instance will become the GUI and not do any processing. Any instance that later joins the HPC will wait for messages and process them until they terminate.

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking for. Does it mean there will always be multiple processes instead of threads when running a MPI application?

Comment: Yes, you start as many processes as you want in the HPC cluster, but only the first started one gets the gui.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to create 2 threads after click a 'Run' button"

Since, you have VS 2010, I am not sure of std::thread compatibility. You could use [MFC's threading API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx) as follows -

```
CWinThread* myThread = AfxBeginThread(myThreadFunc, &threadInfoStruct);
```

[image]

You can use `PostThreadMessage` API to relay information between various MFC threads, i.e. from GUI to Business logic, and thus into MPI threads and back.

Of course, if your compiler supports `std::thread`, that is the way to go.

Related to `std::thread`, often the most correct way to implement what you want is to use `std::async`. Read up about thread based programming vs task based programming in *Effective Modern C++*.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use other API or libraries to achieve parallelism for the reason that I have explained in my comments & Edit of the question. p.s. I didn't down vote your answer though.

Comment: I thought you suggested to use MFC threads or std::thread to re-implement the parallelism part of my existing codebase and that's why I said this is not an option because it will involve a lot of work. Now I just realized/understood that you are actually suggesting to use a separate thread to launch my MPI software. This is similar to the Option 1 in Emily L's answer. Thanks.

Comment: @newbie try to stay with Modern C++11 style as much as possible. You will  be thankful for your choice later.

Comment: but I'm not so sure how to implement this idea in practice. To run a MPI program using MS-MPI, I think I have to use mpiexec.exe to launch the executable first and if I then pass the parameter like -n 2 myprogram.exe, it will just create two instances of the whole program, and in each program (process), it will then create a GUI thread and some business logic threads, which is not really what I want... I think our misunderstanding comes from here...